# Consuming a WSDL in Grails

Tags: grails, wsdl

I have been handed a .WSDL file which I need to test within a Grails Framework.

Any suggestions how to go about this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the http://grails.org/plugin/cxf and http://grails.org/plugin/cxf-client plugins. They're easy to use and backed by Apache CXF - https://cxf.apache.org/

The client plugin has a wsdl2java script that will generate code that you can use in your Grails app.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with documentation itself: http://grails.org/Calling+External+WebServices